# In a Computational Graph, how to calculate the total upstream gradient of a node with multiple upstreams?

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, graphs

Given a Computation Graph with a node (like the one below), I understand that I can use the upstream gradient dL/dz to calculate all of my downstream gradients.

But what if there are *multiple* upstreams? Would the final upstream gradient just be the sum of the derivatives? Or the product? Or the mean? Or something else?

For example, instead of just 1 upstream: `[z]`, we are given 3 upstreams: `[z0, z1, z2]`:

```
dL/dz = dL/dz0 + dL/dz1 + dL/dz2          // sum?
dL/dz = dL/dz0 * dL/dz1 * dL/dz2          // or product?
dL/dz = (dL/dz0 + dL/dz1 + dL/dz2) / 3    // or mean?
```

[image: gradients of a node in a computation graph]

Comment: I think it is the sum but not sure...

Comment: After some testing, I have found that the sum is the correct answer and I have answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical Computational Graph Node, its "Final Upstream Gradient" (`dL/dz` in the above case) is equal to the **sum** of all `n` upstream gradients (`z0, z1, z2` in the above case):

```
dL/dz = dL/dz0 + dL/dz1 + ... + dL/dzn
```